# java Map<K,V> keys as Object?

Tags: java, dictionary, generics

Why is java's `Map<K,V>` declaring the methods like this

```
V get(Object key) {....}
or
boolean containsKey(Object key) {....}
```

I was expecting those to be

```
V get(K key) {....}
or
boolean containsKey(K key) {....}
```

instead.

Got bitten by this, defined a `Map<String,String>` and happily called `myMap.get(myEnum)`, got no compiler error. Yay!

Why bother with specifying K (for type safety, haha) if they prefer the 'flexibility' of Object?

Thanks

Comment: You can't count how often I got bitten by this as well. What you could to is provide some utility method that accepts a map and a key of the correct type, e.g. something like `static <K, V> V get( Map<K, V> map, K key ) { return map.get(key); }`

Comment: sure, but why not have this 'fixed' in the java library itself? I understand that equals is used, but that is the unsafe direction, in a place where it could be avoided. For getting what? Why do I bother declaring Map<K,V> if I can always read via .get(Object key)?

Comment: Well, that's a good question. They could have put it into the interface as a default function, e.g. `safeGet()` or similar, but I'd guess there's a reason why they didn't - maybe there already is a library method in either the JDK itself or something like Apache Commons or Google Guava that I don't know yet.